# seeing multiple log entries for one error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web api controller which is calling a service (using Mediatr) to get back some data, I tried to force an error to get exception logging to work.  But I'm noticing that for 1 error I see 3 entries in the logs, I would assume 1 error = 1 entry, the RequestId is the same for all 3 entries.

In Program.cs after the builder.Build() I have:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
```

My ErrorsController:

```
    [Route("/error")]
    public IActionResult HandleError([FromServices] IHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
    {
        if (!hostEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // if we hit this outside development return 404
            return NotFound();
        }

        var exception = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>().Error!;

        return Problem(
         detail: exception.StackTrace,
         title: exception.Message
        );
    }
```

I'm throwing a test error in the service class with:

```
throw new Exception("something wrong");
```

Now when I hit that method in the log (db and console) I see 3 entries:

HTTP "GET" "/api/query/staff" responded 500 in 593.6407 ms -> Has StackTrace

An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. -> Has same StackTrace as above

HTTP "GET" "/error" responded 500 in 43.4958 ms -> No StackTrace

they all have the same RequestId.

I was trying to log just once, so it's easier to find the exception in the logs, rather than see it 3 times, which i'm assuming is from the service->controller (which called service)->error controller.

Comment: First, can you clarify what your question is? -- it's not clear. Having said that, that 500 Error from `'GET' '/error'` indicates to me that a different error is occurring.  are you actually able to do a breakpoint and catch on the line that does `return Problem (...` ?

Comment: if your question is along the lines of '[How] do I [log] just once, so it's easier to find the exception in the logs'... well, the log entries have different meanings here.  1.) A 500 error occurred in this request, 2.) an error in this request occurred and it is unhandled, and 3.) the page registered to handle unhandled errors is erroring (I think). but there are means to log framework/app errors in different scopes to different sources... perhaps that is what is best suited here.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to see if there is a way to get just 1 error logged, rather then 3, so it's easier to locate the error in the logs.  But considering it's different scopes and it's showing the error moving up the chain, that's fine.